# Jquery - Adding on top of dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the below code that is working great for me!

```
$("#custom_logo").css("marginLeft", $(".rt-container:first").css("marginLeft"));
```

But my problem is that I want to be able to add 15 more pixels to the margin but the below code does not work at all.

```
$("#custom_logo").css("marginLeft", $(".rt-container:first").css("marginLeft")+15);
```

I am presuming that is it because the output will be somthing like '260px15' rather than '275px' which is what I am aiming for. I was wondering if there was a way to do this simply that I am over looking?

Comment: Debug the steps. You'll see you're adding a string "15px" and a number and `"15px"+15` isn't pretty.

Comment: dystroy, his original post includes that he realizes this is the problem :)

Comment: First try and print $(".rt-container:first").css("marginLeft") in console. If it works implement the below answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work for you!

```
$("#custom_logo").css("marginLeft", parseInt($(".rt-container:first").css("marginLeft")) +15);
```

parseInt() can remove the 'px' from the end of the string and convert to an integer.

Comment: Thanks since I don't used much js I didn't realise paraseInt worked in that way :) Works Perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#custom_logo").css("marginLeft",

 ($(".rt-container:first").css("marginLeft").slice(0,-2) +15 )* 1)
```